# By MJML, how to create a responsive email template with nested columns?

Tags: email-templates, mjml, responsive-emails

In [MJML](https://mjml.io) seems there is no way to nest mj-column's, So how do you create nested columns?

This is what I'm trying to build:

[image: screenshot of columns]

I tried using mj-section and mj-wrapper too but seems none of these tags can be nested.

Answer (score 2):

You're right about not nesting MJML mj-columns.

This design is tough to make responsive.

You'll want to use good old HTML. Maybe you'll want to use the long-traditional embedded tables so often used in email HTML.

In MJML, you can use raw HTML in mj-raw, mj-table, and mj-text. Among those, maybe mj-table is your best choice; it also substitutes for the HTML tag <table></table>.

You can equally do it in the others if you prefer; they'd need that tag.

BTW, lots of questions just like this get prompt answers at https://slack.mjml.io/.